# How to debug a Thunderbird addon/extension's JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, javascript-debugger

I want to develop a Thunderbird 12 addon. I have written a simple JS function. (File: "chrome\content\myApp.js"). This file is called by a xul-'onclick'-event. I have packed my addon as a .xpi file and then I have installed it. (All ok, it's working!)

Now I'd like to debug my JS functions. But I can't find a working JS Debugger. 
I have tried this addons:

- "Javascript Debugger"(0.9.89). Not working: The thread doesn't stop at my breakpoints.
- Firebug(1.7.2) + Chromebug(1.7.2). Not working: I can't enable the JS debug tab. (**Update**: I also can't set/change a "context")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no such thing as a decent debugger for chrome (addons) javascript. Chromebug has been long abandoned, venkman doesn't work, addon authors are a little bit stranded there. A new debugging API called JSD2 is in the works at Mozilla, but it looks from the [wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/DevTools/Features/Debugger) that it's mostly targeted at content (webpage) javascript, not chrome (addons) javascript, at least not in the short term.

Fortunately, a very recent effort seems to have paid off: there's now a way to execute easily small snippets of javascript in a decent console-like window. See http://mikeconley.ca/blog/2012/05/11/scratchpad-ported-to-thunderbird-kinda/ for the details :).

Answer (score 5):

Happily we once again have a debugger for Thunderbird! You need a newer/nightly version, but hanks to Philipp Kewisch's summer of code project we can use the Firefox debugger to remotely debug Thunderbird. More details at the following links:
http://kewisch.wordpress.com/2013/09/22/thunderbird-developer-tools-wrapup/
http://kewisch.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/the-thunderbird-remote-debugger-is-alive/
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=876636

If you are really committed to TB12, you can debug on the nightly then test on TB12.